# how to get byobu to open splits as a login shell (bash --login)

Tags: byobu

Just ran across byobu and being a screen and tmux user I thought I'd give it a try as it already does a number of things I hack together in screen and tmux and it looks pretty well thought through.  However, when I open new sessions or splits, basically anything that launches a new command prompt, it isn't creating them as "login shells" along the same lines as "bash --login", which processes /etc/profile and the cascade of profiles involved.

There's probably an easy/direct way to get it to launch them as login shells but I can't seem to find it and hoped someone knows how to configure that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!  The answer seems to be to add

```
set -g default-command '/bin/bash --login'
```

to $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/.tmux.conf

Once that's added then new sessions appear to be started as login shells for tmux sessions.

(from the byobu man page - BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/byobu if defined, and $HOME/.byobu otherwise.)